# Cert based Mutual SSL with RESTful WCF service

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

I have a certificate based mutual(two-way) SSL WCF RESTful service, which is hosted in a windows application. The server uses a port to which is bound a self signed certificate. The certificate is present in "LocalMachine" in "My" store. In the same "My" store is also the client certificate. Both client and server certificates have their names same as the machine name. The client and server configurations are given below:

**Client:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
      <webHttp />
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeName="My" findValue="F50C62754783EC741F6E84E25888D17CBC145691" />
        <serviceCertificate>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBinding_Conf">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://mymachine:8088/Service" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_Conf"
      contract="RESTfulLib.IService" name="WebHttpBinding_NAme" />
</client>
```

**Server:**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="7975794831242F2D39ED3B1BC8323EAF5DA2CA11" storeName="My"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBinding_Conf">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="RESTfulLib.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://mymachine:8088/Service"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_Conf" contract="RESTfulLib.IService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

However, I have been getting this error during the SSL handshake:

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
```

Enabling detailed WCF logs reveals that we have this error during the hand shake:

```
System.Net Error: 0 : [11504] Decrypt returned SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE.
```

I have tried the setting, but this also does not help:

```
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

The certificates are copied also to Trusted Root CAs store and there is a ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback which returns true in all cases(!)

Any answers would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As your certificate is self-signed you have to had some extra code to your client like that.

Before instanciating your WCF client, you should add :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = TrustAllCertificatesCallback;
```

TrustAllCertificatesCallback is a callback method which performs service certificate validation. Here is a sample :

```
internal static bool TrustAllCertificatesCallback(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
   X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert);
   return certificate.Verify();
}
```

You also have to install your certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authority certificates store, and finally add to your client endpoint configuration :

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://mymachine:8088/Service" behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_Conf"
      contract="RESTfulLib.IService" name="WebHttpBinding_NAme">
    <identity>
      <dns value="<<<your certificate name>>>" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

You have to ensure that your certificates are well installed and configured to be accessed :

1. You first have to import the private key of your certificates in the **local computer** Peronnal store, not in the current user Personnal store. It is important, if a service account have to use the certificate.
2. If you use self-signed certificate, be sure that the public certificate is installed in the **local computer** trusted root authority store.
3. Allow users to access your certificate : right click on the private certificate (local computer/personnal), and choose All Task and then Manage Private Keys.

Comment: Rom, I already have a ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback which returns true in all cases(!). The certificates(both) are copied to Trusted Root CAs. Secondly where do I need to put the <identity> xml?

Comment: Do you have activated WCF traces ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same error: 

    System.Net Error: 0 : [10796] Decrypt returned SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE.

    System.Net Information: 0 : [12032] SecureChannel#30384602 - We have user-provided certificates. The server has specified 133 issuer(s). Looking for certificates that match any of the issuers.
System.Net Information: 0 : [12032] SecureChannel#30384602 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.

Comment: Where do you have installed your certificates on the client machine ?

Comment: Client and server are both on the same machine. The certificates are on this common machine.

Comment: Have you installed the certificate in the computer store (not in the current user store) ? Have you configured the acces to the private keys for the user who execute the server and the client ?

Comment: "Have you configured the acces to the private keys for the user who execute the server and the client ?" - is there something special that needs to be done? I have not done anything apart from importing the *.pfx file, which has both the public and private keys.

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated. See my further answer ;-)